# How do I cite a pullout of a news release?

Tags: citations, bibtex

How do I cite the pullout? Should I just cite the original? What would the bibtex be?

The pullout has information that is extremely useful, and I have not found the thing I needed anywhere else.

(I feel like I'm overthinking this, but this is one of the most obscure formats that I have had to cite, and I'm inexperienced...)

The link to the news release. https://www.jisc.ac.uk/sites/default/files/janet-news-24-april-2014.pdf

The link to the pullout. https://www.jisc.ac.uk/sites/default/files/janet-news-24-pull-out-april-2014.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you just cite the title, *"1984-2014: 30 years of the Janet network"*, publisher and other details same as usual?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your preferred style, either of the following APA variants should be fine:

> Jisc (2014) 1984-2014: 30 years of the Janet network. *Janet News **24** (Special Edition Pullout)*, April 2014. https://www.jisc.ac.uk/sites/default/files/janet-news-24-pull-out-april-2014.pdf
>
> Jisc (2014, April) 1984-2014: 30 years of the Janet network. *Janet News **24** (Special Edition Pullout)*. https://www.jisc.ac.uk/sites/default/files/janet-news-24-pull-out-april-2014.pdf

Also, since company newsletters on the internet have an unstable repository, I recommend you download and save both the newsletter and the pullout on your local drive and keep it with your supplementary files.  This is just in case the link breaks or changes, the company goes out of business, or the newsletter is lost.  If you have your own personal copy of the newsletter then your reference will not be lost in this event.